# Cannot build has_one child object from nested form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-forms, has-one

I have a User model, which has_one Spec. In my User model, I did specify accepts_nested_attributes_for :spec, and attr_accessible :spec_attributes.

I created a nested form for User and Spec (nested). The hash sent to #create method looks fine:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XXX", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Adam", 
  "last_name"=>"Smith", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", 
  "spec_attributes"=>{"highest_degree"=>""}}
```

However, I have this error of cannot build association spec:

```
ArgumentError (Cannot build association spec. Are you trying to build a polymorphic 
one-to-one association?)
```

My Spec is not polymorphic though. When I try to call build_spec on an User object, I got an error saying that this is a private message. I opened up the source code for this error, and it says that this message error appears when User does not response to method build_spec.

What did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you need more details for anyone to answer the question.

Comment: Also naming a model spec is probably a bad idea.  I have believe it's not causing this issue but could cause plenty of other issues.

Comment: Thank you. I did have issues with Spec before. But the refactoring in Rails is a pain (I am using textMate), so I'll have to leave with it for some time.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I created a private method whose name is build_spec, thus override default method of build_association.